# Is there a difference between calling a function with a goroutine and wrapping a functions code in a goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm relatively new to Golang and I'm trying to wrap my head around the semantics of goroutines.
Is there a difference between:

```
func someFunc() {
    for {
        //some code handled by a persistent connection
    }
}

go someFunc()
```

and

```
func someFunc() {
    go func() {
        for {
            //some code handled by a persistent connection
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Could I get some insight as to why this was closed so I can improve questions in the future? It says it's an opinion based question, but my intention was to get a better understanding of how goroutines execute under different circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of what you're trying to communicate. Generally functions should represent behavior that isn't tied to the mode of operation of that behavior. If someday your code becomes all asynchronous because of some business concern, it shouldn't require touching any code inside of `someFunc`.

For that reason I would prefer the former to the latter, but ultimately both are spawning a goroutine and executing code on that thread. The advantage to the former is that running `someFunc` synchronously becomes possible.

---

There are other small differences as well. The first definition of someFunc is running until it finishes its behavior. Let's imagine a long-running `expensiveAction` is taken during someFunc, such that the definition becomes:

```golang
func someFunc() {
    ok := expensiveAction()
    if !ok {
        panic("Something bad happened")
    }
}
```

and

```golang
func someFunc() {
    go func() {
        ok := expensiveAction()
        if !ok {
            panic("Something bad happened")
        }
    }()
}
```

The first definition of `someFunc`, when called, will run until `expensiveAction` has finished. The second definition will define the anonymous function, spin up the goroutine and schedule its execution, then immediately exit. This could make performance testing more difficult, or even create subtle timing bugs.